# Execute Outlook macro from .bat file

Tags: vba, batch-file, outlook

I have a macro within outlook that downloads attachments from emails

I want to create a .bat file that opens outlook and executes my macro

for eg my .bat file looks like this at the moment

```
Set MacroName=Extract_Outlook_Email_Attachments()
start Outlook.exe
```

And my macro code Extract_Outlook_Email_Attachments() is saved in Outlook module

Can someone help me on what my ThisOutlooksession object should contain for this to run

Or if you know another way to execute an outlook macro from .bat file

thanks

Comment: Why not create a VBS file that uses Outlook Object Model to do what you need to do?

Comment: If you use vbscript then this can be used to run your code - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d455ba89-b2d4-4dda-8b13-54e941f7f71a/ltapplicationrungt-equivalent-for-microsoft-outlook?forum=outlookdev

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko How would one go about doing that, I dont have experience writing vbscript

Comment: Create an instance of the "Outlook.Application" object using CreateObject functions and use Outlook Object Model to do what you need. Do you not already have a macro (aka VB script) that you want to run?

Answer (score 2):

You just only need to know the location of outlook.exe - which could be tricky, then you can use /autorun argument to run a VBA script. In my case, I also needed to force close the Outlook to function properly, so this is the content of my .bat file:

`taskkill -IM OUTLOOK.EXE -F
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /autorun SendOutMyEmail`

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are several ways to do this.  Here is one idea.

1.

Click the "Start" button. Type "Schedule Tasks" in the search box and press "Enter."

2.

Click "Create Basic Task" under "Actions" in the far-right pane. Select a name for your task next to "Name" and a description for your task next to "Description" on the wizard's first screen. Click "Next" to proceed.

3.

Select the time you want Outlook to start under "When Do You Want the Task to Start?" Select "Daily," "Weekly," "Monthly" or "One Time" to select a specific time frequency. Select "When the Computer Starts" or "When I Log On" to open Outlook when one of these events occurs. Click "Next" after selecting your option.

4.

Use the drop-down lists to select a date and time if you chose to start Outlook daily, weekly, monthly or one time. If you selected to start Outlook weekly, click the box next to the day of the week you want the program to open. If you selected to start it monthly, select the exact day of the month you want it to run. Click "Next" to continue.

5.

Click "Start a Program" on the "What Action Do You Want the Task to Perform?" step and click "Next." Click the "Browse" button next to "Program/Script." Locate Microsoft Outlook in the dialog box, then press "Enter." For Microsoft Office 2010 users, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Outlook.exe" is typically the default location.

6.

Click "Next" and "Finish" to save your scheduled task for Outlook. The program will start at the time of the scheduled task.